# Typegraphql resolver for existing class

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

How can I write a resolver in typegraphql for a class I can not edit myself?

Normally I would have the situation that I write a class e.g.

```
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field()
  f_name!: string;

  @Field()
  l_name!: string;

  @Field()
  email!: string;
}
```

And then I can add a resolver which returns this class

```
  @Query(() => User)
  user():Promise<User>{
    some code which returns a User
  }
```

Now I am using a package which defines a class `transactionOutput` and I would like to use this object as a return for my graphql query. How can I accomplish this without editing that class?

Comment: So... what are part of this are you having trouble with? Creating the class?

Comment: Well, the class `transactionOutput` is defined in this package and I can't go and add @Field decorators in that class. (I could fork their repo and then add that but I'm sure there is a better way xD)

Comment: Well I don't know any other solutions... You could manually call the decorators on the class...

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Oh no, actually because of the `ObjectType` class decorator I don't think this would work out. I think copying the class is your best option now.